# forward requests to cpanel server through haproxy

Tags: redirect, load-balancing, cpanel, haproxy

I deployed an loadbalanced infrustructure. I am using haproxy as the loadbalancer and cpanel as backend webservers. I created a test host on the cpanel, and I can see the site in browser when I configure the website in my /etc/host with the cpanel server ip address. But when I change the ip to the loadbalancer it forwards the requests to /usr/local/apache/htdocs/ and I get the default cpanel server page. What configurations should I use in haproxy to redirects requests correctly?
Any help is appreciated.

```
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2     #Log configuration

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy             #Haproxy running under user and group "haproxy"
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#HAProxy Monitoring Config
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
listen haproxy2-monitoring *:8080                #Haproxy Monitoring run on port 8080
    mode http
 option forwardfor
    option httpclose
    stats enable
    stats show-legends
    stats refresh 5s
    stats uri /stats                             #URL for HAProxy monitoring
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth lb2:F6khdTrt9g            #User and Password for login to the monitoring dashboard
    stats admin if TRUE
    default_backend app-main                    #This is optionally for monitoring backend

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# FrontEnd Configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend main
    bind *:80
    default_backend app-main

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# BackEnd roundrobin as balance algorithm
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend app-main


    balance roundrobin                                     #Balance algorithm
    application is up and healty - 200 status code

    server cpanel1 192.168.1.110:80 check
    server cpanel2 192.168.1.111:80 check

Cpanel apache config:
Listen 0.0.0.0:80

# BEGIN: HTTP vhosts list

<VirtualHost 88.99.219.13:80>
  ServerName wiki.serversetup.ir
  ServerAlias mail.wiki.serversetup.ir www.wiki.serversetup.ir
  DocumentRoot /home/wiki/public_html
  ServerAdmin webmaster@wiki.serversetup.ir
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/wiki.serversetup.ir combined
  <IfModule log_config_module>
    <IfModule logio_module>
      CustomLog /etc/apache2/logs/domlogs/wiki.serversetup.ir-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  ## User wiki # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
  <IfModule userdir_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_itk.c>
      <IfModule !ruid2_module>
        UserDir disabled
        UserDir enabled wiki
      </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  # Enable backwards compatible Server Side Include expression parser for Apache versions >= 2.4.
  # To selectively use the newer Apache 2.4 expression parser, disable SSILegacyExprParser in
  # the user's .htaccess file.  For more information, please read:
  #    http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_include.html#ssilegacyexprparser
  <IfModule include_module>
    <Directory "/home/wiki/public_html">
      SSILegacyExprParser On
    </Directory>
  </IfModule>



  <IfModule suphp_module>
    suPHP_UserGroup wiki wiki
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule suexec_module>
    <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
      SuexecUserGroup wiki wiki
 </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule ruid2_module>
    RMode config
    RUidGid wiki wiki
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mpm_itk.c>
    # For more information on MPM ITK, please read:
    #   http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/
    AssignUserID wiki wiki
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/wiki/public_html/cgi-bin/
  </IfModule>


  # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
  # Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/wiki/wiki.serversetup.ir/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
# END: HTTP vhosts list
```

Comment: Provide your current haproxy config and cpanel's server config?

Comment: Hi, I edit my firsh post and send haproxy config and cpanel's server config.

Comment: It seems that vhost for cpanel (wiki.serversetup.ir). is available only for request coming from 88.99.219.13, but haproxy has configured upstream with 192.168.1.110 and 192.168.1.111. Because there's no vhost for 192.168.1.x apache handle it with default one.

Comment: Tanks alot. Exactly right. I got careless.